# How to convert words from text area/box into arrays for database comparison in php

Tags: php, keyword

I'm new to php and i would like to know, how can i convert the contents of a text area or text box into separate words and put them into separate arrays so that i can use those arrays for comparing specific keywords inside a MySQL database... hoping that someone can help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [php function Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Example

```
<?php
// Example 1
$pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
$pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

// Example 2
$data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
echo $user; // foo
echo $pass; // *

?>
```

Comment: what if someone else does the input, and their are no given values, like inside a text area or text box, when you type sentences how can i convert every word into an array for comparison to a databse?

Comment: @user1557255... above given are just examples. You need to get data written in text box using post or get method into variable and then use explode function